# Initial Seed for LFSR in PSpice

Tags: digital-logic, spice, pspice

I am implementing a Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) in Pspice A/D with a new logic family. Anyways, to initiate the random number generation I am required to feed in some value to the circuit, to be specific, the output of all the D-latches can not be zero initially so I am trying to make the output of any D-latch '1' initially. It should be done such that after the initialization the circuit works by itself. I tried using a fixed voltage source but that does not work, quite obviously.
Please suggest anything you may find applicable to this.

Below is the circuit I am trying to make:

[image]

And just in case it may help, I am trying to get results like these:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use the ".ic" *(initial condition)* directive.

Name any node (or find a node name) and then add the directive .ic V(nodename)=*required voltage*V

In this case, SPICE may struggle without an initial condition for both XOR inputs. I would probably set initial conditions for every flip-flop in this situation.

Update: where to add ic directive.

I would put the directive at the top level node to start with.

Comment: If i am making use of subcircuits here, where exactly should i point the .ic command